# Repeat section of an array multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat

What is the best way to repeat sections of an array multiple times and put the elements into another array?

For example, convert each item 3 times from this:

```
var array = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

into this:

```
var array = ['Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Tue', 'Tue', etc...]
```

Comment: Create a new array and copy over each member *n* times. Maybe use *reduce* and *push*.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't overly complicated and you are expected to have shown some effort to resolve problems yourself

Comment: Crucial information is the order of the final array important? i.e. three "Mon" then three "Tue" etc. or is it ok to just have the total results in the final array?

Comment: Wow, never thought I'd see a recommendation for regex...

Comment: Sorry @charlietfl I'm kinda new to this :/ I did try with push but I find loops a little tricky.

Comment: That doesn't excuse you from not showing those attempts. You learn more when people can help you see your problems. Otherwise it just looks like you expect others to write code for you

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative with `for` loop (without forEach as one answer used) and here is an article that shows that the for loop is faster than forEach 
https://josephscott.org/archives/2014/10/javascript-performance-for-vs-foreach/

```
var array = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2r7nqqyt/

You have various alternatives now.

Comment: Careful with performance comparisons. Browsers are updated frequently, the built–in iterators were quite slow in early implementations but testing in recent browsers shows that they can be as fast as loops. Also, what the loop is doing greatly affects how much it can be optimised.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var temp=[];

var array = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

array.forEach(function(x){
   for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
     temp.push(x);
})
console.log(temp);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6uvujfe/)

Comment: Why not push three times, instead of `for`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y6uvujfe/1/). Code: `array.forEach(function (x) {
    temp.push(x);
    temp.push(x);
    temp.push(x);
})`

Comment: @Tushar user may need n times of repeat then he just have to repalce 3 with a variable and value. that  won't need much  effort to do that

Answer (score 0):

To be clever you could just chain two prototype methods together...

```
var array = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];


var newArr = array.map(function(day){return [day, day, day];}).reduce(function(a, b){return a.concat(b);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/argz7zro/

of course, you would only do this if you want to be slow....

Three methods compared here:

Using prototype methods, using for loops, using forEach.

http://jsperf.com/arr-prototype-vs-loops